# Dart: Get the currency code given a locale

Tags: dart, formatting, currency

Specific Dart question. Given a locale (i.e. `'en_US'`, `'es_ES'`, ...), how can I get the associated currency symbol?

Do you know if there's a library similar to `Currency` in Java? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `intl` package (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl)

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

main() {
  var formatEnUs = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: 'en_US');
  print(formatEnUs.currencySymbol); // $
  print(formatEnUs.currencyName); // USD

  var formatEs = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: 'es_ES');
  print(formatEs.currencySymbol); // €
  print(formatEs.currencyName); // EUR
}
```